# Subscribing to query params not working after returning to the page

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a page: `/news` with query parameter `page`.

I have a subscription to query params:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        ...
    });
}
```

If I open `/news` and navigate to `/news?page=1` then subscription works fine.

But if I open `/news` and navigate to `/another-page` and then again navigate to `/news` and navigate to `/news?page=1` then subscription is not working anymore. Why does it happen? I use Angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preserveQueryParams` or `queryParamsHandling`. This will keep the query in the url if you go to another route. So if you have `/news?page=1` and go to another route the query will stay `another-page?page=1`.

This will result in that the query stay visible where you apply this and you can re-use it when got back to the news route.

Source: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParamsHandling